# Ignoring NLog Configuration referenced in other assembly

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a unique problem with the NLog. I have a third-party assembly we use into our project. They have used the NLog into their project and referenced NLog configuration into their configuration which I don't have access to. 
I initially had a problem even adding the NLog to a project since both version of dlls were different. I had to download the source code of NLog and change the assembly name since alias was not working for me (OR I didn't know how to use it.)
After giving my own assembly name, NLog started wotrking but.. It started logging third-party log information too with it. Looks like they were not careful enough when defining the logger and they just defined (*). Now my question is, how do I avoid their stuff from logging in to my file? I have also tried setting it to final = true. 
Here is how my very simple configuration file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- 
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
    <!-- add your targets here -->

    <!--
    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
    -->

    <target name="errorLog" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="${basedir}/logs/error/${shortdate}.log" 
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}"

    />
    <target name="generalLog" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="C:/logs/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"/>   

  </targets>


  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="Errors" writeTo="errorLog" minlevel="Warn"/>
    <logger name="EBusiness.Model.*" writeTo="generalLog" levels="Trace,Debug,Info" final="true"/>

    <!--
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f" />
    -->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are writing to the root logger, you should configure the root logger to not log to anywhere you care (maybe point it at a console logger) and your application can log to a specific logger which does write to your files.

Ugly, but should work.

For example:
Add this target:

`<target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />`

And Change the `*` rule to be:

`<logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal " writeTo="console" />`

Then, Add your own logger rule, say something like:

`<logger name="MyNameSpace.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" final="true" />`

Assuming you have a `logfile` target defined pointing at your file.

Comment: Or, you can switch to Log4net ;)

Comment: Can you please provide me some samples? I tried the following.. but their stuff is still logged on mine..
<logger name="Errors" writeTo="errorLog" minlevel="Warn"/>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="Spammer" levels="Trace,Debug,Info" final="true"/>
    <logger name="EBusiness.Model.*" writeTo="generalLog" levels="Trace,Debug,Info" final="true"/>
If you see the loggers, I have created a root logger point to some other file and then very specific logger for my class. It is still logging their stuff into mine and their file is not created

Comment: In that case, I guess i'm missing something important about how they are using the configuration - sorry I cannot help more.

Comment: I tried the solution you mentioned and that doesn't seem to be working. Looks like their configuration file is loaded after mine so it overrides mine?? I have no clue. They also blocked Log4Net by including the dll into their assembly. I am using Enterprise Library logging but it is very sluggish and doesn't seem to be async.

Comment: I have another approach we could try, changing the configuration via code after NLog is already configured. I am not sure that would work but look [here](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API) for more information. At least you could query the existing configuration and see what is really in there. Let us know what you found.